# How can I add BoomMenu library from GitHub to my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, github, gradle

I want to add the boom menu from GitHub to my app, I can't figure out what I'm supposed to add in order to implement the library, this is the link to GitHub https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu.

Comment: You just need to add implementation 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1' to your Gradle

Comment: do i need to add it to my root Gradle or my app.gradle?

Comment: To your app Gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see informaton library he said

you should add this

```
compile 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1'
```

and then in dependency add these code :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.nightonke</groupId>
<artifactId>boommenu</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where should i add this code <dependency>
<groupId>com.nightonke</groupId>
<artifactId>boommenu</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>? gradle?

Comment: in the app gradle copy dependency there

Comment: see this tutorial to use the boom menu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAvvDySvJFc @Shmebulouk